# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean

Tags: struts

I have placed all tld on proper place and checked all setting, still I am in same well.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean"

Comment: What version of Struts? (And what do you mean by "placed all tld on proper place"?)

Comment: I am using struts 1.2, I kept all tld in web-inf folder and made entry in web.xml. Thks

Comment: 1.2.? In any case, declaring TLD entries in the web.xml hasn't been required for years; what server are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't need to declare anything in your web.xml, nor should you need any external TLD.

Comment: Have you Cleaned and rebuilt the project?  Adding a TLD that was missing before won't trigger revalidation of your JSP file.  Where is that TLD, actually?

Answer (score 0):

You might not have included the tag library in the set of libraries in the lib folder.
struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this also
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%> 
i think this is the solution